# Ember not updating template when attribute of controller is modified

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have one attribute which I'm modifying through an action, but Ember is not updating the rendered template.

My controller:

```
selected_rows_id: [],
actions: {
    selectRow(rowId) {
        let selected_rows = this.get('selected_rows_id');
        if (selected_rows.indexOf(rowId) === -1) {
            selected_rows.push(rowId);
            // selected_rows.pushObject(rowId); does not work either
        }
        this.set('selected_rows_id', selected_rows);
    },
}
```

In my template I'm using `{{selected_rows_id}}` to show my elements

I've created a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/72aeb8a5d7c9204fdb7cf74e8597f787?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C) to demonstrate what I did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was nothing wrong in the action. The problem was with the template. Also, another way to do the logic of my code was use `addObject` which checks whether the element was already inserted or not.

One cannot use an attribute if it is an structure like I was doing. 
You have to use the `{{each}}` helper and it will take care to render the updated value.

```
{{#each selected_rows_id as |rowId|}}
    {{rowId}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: I think this is correct for your situation. Handlebar won't show anything if your {{property}} is array or object

Answer (score 2):

Use `pushObject` not `push`:

```
actions: {
    selectRow(rowId) {
        let selected_rows = this.get('selected_rows_id');
        selected_rows.pushObject(rowId);
    },
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I've tried.

Comment: Aha yes, you need to iterate over that array.

Comment: I knew it was something trivial. Thanks anyway :)